# Proving $\left \{ a_{n}b_{n} \right \}$ diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The question is:

> If $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}$ and $\left \{ b_{n} \right \}$ are both sequences that diverge to infinity, prove that the sequence $\left \{ a_{n}b_{n} \right \}$ diverges to infinity.

The problem I am having with this is that, although I know the definition of a divergent sequence, I am not given an explicit sequence.  Therefore, I am having trouble formulating an argument.

Can anyone give me a start?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Since $b_n$ diverges to infinity, after some $N$, $b_n \geq 1$ for all $n \geq N$. Therefore, for any $n \geq N$ $a_nb_n \geq a_n$. What can you conclude now? Hint: Comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A>0$ be given. By definition, there exist $N_1, N_2 \in \mathbb N$ such that
\begin{equation}|a_n|>\sqrt A \text{ whenever } n \geq N_1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}|b_n|>\sqrt A \text{ whenever } n \geq N_2.
\end{equation}

Set $N=\max\{N_1, N_2\}$. So we have $|a_n b_n|>A$ whenever $n \geq N$. Therefore, $a_nb_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For each $M>0$ you can find some $N_1$ such that $a_n > \sqrt{M}$ for $n >N_1$.
Same way  you can find some $N_2$ such that $b_n > \sqrt{M}$ for $n >N_2$.

What happens when $n > \max\{N_1,N_2 \}$?